# Is it possible to create a custom, animated MKAnnotationView?

Tags: iphone, mapkit, mkannotation

I'm trying to simulate the user location animation in MapKit (where-by the user's position is represented by a pulsating blue dot). I've created a custom subclass of MKAnnotationView and in the drawRect method I'm attempting to cycle through a set of colors. Here's a simpler implementation of what I'm doing:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
float magSquared = event.magnitude * event.magnitude;
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
if (idx == -1) {
    r[0] = 1.0; r[1] = 0.5; r[2] = 0;
    b[0] = 0; b[1] = 1.0; b[2] = 0.5;
    g[0] = 0.5; g[1] = 0; g[2] = 1.0;
    idx = 0;
}
// CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0 - magSquared * 0.015, 0.211, .6);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, r[idx], g[idx], b[idx], 0.75);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, rect);
idx++;
if (idx > 3) idx = 0;
}
```

Unfortunately this just causes the annotations to be one of the 3 different colors and doesn't cycle through them. Is there a way to force the MKAnnotations to continually redraw so that it appears to be animated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are free to call `setNeedsDisplay` on your annotation view whenever you want it to redraw. The easiest way to do this would be for the annotation view itself to set up a timer that fired every 1/60th of a second or so.

A more sophisticated approach would be to put your drawing code into a custom `CALayer` and apply a repeating Core Animation animation to it. See [my answer to "Animating a custom property of CALayer subclass"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395382/animating-a-custom-property-of-calayer-subclass/2396461#2396461) for an approach.

Comment: Thanks. Adding <pre>[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.25 target:self selector:@selector(setNeedsDisplay) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];</pre> works though I'll definitely look into your CALayer suggestion.