# Custom animatable properties in SceneKit

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-animation, osx-mountain-lion, scenekit

I know it's possible to create [custom animatable properties in Core Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395382/animating-a-custom-property-of-calayer-subclass), but what about in OS X 10.8's SceneKit framework?  `SCNAnimatable` doesn't seem to expose the same APIs that `CALayer` does for making properties animatable.

In my application, I've got a `SCNNode` subclass called `Starfield`, which I've ported from an old OpenGL application by using a `SCNNodeRendererDelegate`.  Starfields expose a `GLfloat` property called `warpFactor`:

```
@interface Starfield : SCNNode<SCNNodeRendererDelegate> {
    // other stuff that's not really important for this question
    GLfloat warpFactor;
}

@property(nonatomic) GLfloat warpFactor;
@end
```

But when I try to add an animation to it, like so:

```
CABasicAnimation *warp = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"warpFactor"];
warp.toValue = @1.0;
warp.duration = 5.0;
[starfield addAnimation:warp forKey:@"warp"];
```

I get the following in the console:

```
[SCNKit ERROR] warpFactor is not an animatable path (from <unnamed SCNNode 0x1016473c0, no children>)
```

I know SceneKit is brand new, but does anyone happen to know how to make this work?

Comment: I'm genuinely surprised that this is the first question someone has asked here about SceneKit.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SceneKit doesn't support custom animatable keypath

Comment: That certainly seems plausible, but before just giving up, I'd like to confirm that in fact what I want to do is impossible.  Can you point me to docs, or anything else, that confirms this?

Comment: The docs for SceneKit are pretty sparse. I looked and didn't find anything. The error message might be the best you'll get.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping someone else would be able to jump in with a different answer, but it looks like this is probably the best we can figure at least until Apple releases better documentation.  Accepting.

Answer (score 3):

A workaround/hack:

- create a geometry-less node and animate some animatable property on that node, for example the opacity
- use a [SCNSceneRendererDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNSceneRendererDelegate_Protocol/index.html) to hook into the appropriate stage of the rendering process and manually update your custom property with the value of the geometry-less node's animated property (make sure to read the animated property from the node's `presentationNode`)

This solution is ugly, but it allows you to synchronize the animation of the custom property with other animations via [SCNTransaction](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNTransaction_Class/Introduction/SCNTransaction.html) or [CAAnimationGroup](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CAAnimationGroup_class/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: I created an "interpolation node" that did just this: I animated things like CIFilter properties and evaluated the presentation values every frame to do what I needed. It worked pretty well.