# Key Value Coding Use in Swift

Tags: swift, key-value-observing, key-value-coding

I want to know the use of KVO in swift as I read in Apple Doc or any other online articles it states that it provides indirect access to properties and addressable via string. I have a set of doubts.

- If I can set the property directly via **person.name = "John"** they why to use a **Set Value** **for key** name = "John" indirectly
- Apple doc says key-value coding compliant can participate in a wide range of Cocoa technologies like **Core Data**. Why it's used and not in other frameworks
- It is used during runtime or dynamic to set value. How it is?
- Is it TypeSafe and how?
- Its an Objective - C feature then why still used in Swift 4 with latest improvements with **./Type.property** access and set

Comment: KVO is Key Value Observing.

Answer (score 2):

> If I can set the property directly via person.name = "John" they why
>   to use a Set Value for key name = "John" indirectly

Please read [“What is the point of key-value coding?”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386083/what-is-the-point-of-key-value-coding)

---

> Apple doc says
>   key-value coding compliant can participate in a wide range of Cocoa
>   technologies like Core Data. Why it's used and not in other frameworks

It's used where appropriate. It's used where it is helpful and the performance is acceptable. If it's not useful, or if its performance is too low, it's not used.

---

> It is used during runtime or dynamic to set value. How it is?

Key-Value Coding uses the Objective-C runtime to look up getter and setter methods, and to find the types and locations of instance variables if the setters don't exist. See [Friday Q&A 2013-02-08: Let's Build Key-Value Coding](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2013-02-08-lets-build-key-value-coding.html) for a detailed analysis.

Apple documentation briefly describes the implementation of Key-Value Observing [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOImplementation.html). It's short enough to quote entirely:

> Automatic key-value observing is implemented using a technique called
>   *isa-swizzling*.
>
> The `isa` pointer, as the name suggests, points to the object's class
>   which maintains a dispatch table. This dispatch table essentially
>   contains pointers to the methods the class implements, among other
>   data.
>
> When an observer is registered for an attribute of an object the isa
>   pointer of the observed object is modified, pointing to an
>   intermediate class rather than at the true class. As a result the
>   value of the isa pointer does not necessarily reflect the actual class
>   of the instance.
>
> You should never rely on the `isa` pointer to determine class
>   membership. Instead, you should use the `class` method to determine the
>   class of an object instance.

Mike Ash gave a more detailed analysis in [Friday Q&A 2009-01-23](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-01-23.html).

---

> Is it
>   TypeSafe and how?

It's not particularly type safe. For example, it doesn't stop you from storing a `UIView` in a property that's declared as `NSString`, or vice versa.

> Its an Objective - C feature then why still used in
>   Swift 4 with latest improvements with ./Type.property access and set

It's still used because most of Apple's SDK is still implemented in Objective-C, and because it lets you do things that you cannot do in Swift without much more “boilerplate” (manual, repetitive functions). The trade-off is that Objective-C is lower performance. In many, many cases, the lower performance of Objective-C (compared to Swift) is not a significant problem, and the increased dynamism is very helpful.

Comment: Just an addition: My library EVReflection would be impossible without KVC (Or you would need code generation like the Codable protocol does) For more info see https://github.com/evermeer/EVReflection