# UIMotionEffect with custom property

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I'm trying to apply a UIMotionEffect to a custom property on a GLKView subclass. This is my code on the view's setup:

```
UIInterpolatingMotionEffect *horizontalMotionEffect = [[UIInterpolatingMotionEffect alloc] initWithKeyPath:@"customCenter.x" type:UIInterpolatingMotionEffectTypeTiltAlongHorizontalAxis];    
horizontalMotionEffect.minimumRelativeValue = @(-50);
horizontalMotionEffect.maximumRelativeValue = @(50);
[self addMotionEffect:horizontalMotionEffect];
```

The property is defined as:

```
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint customCenter;
```

But when I log the property in the animation loop its alwas 0. What am I missing?

Comment: Check out this amazing example ... http://rogchap.com/2013/08/23/custom-uiview-animations-with-vector-graphics/

And note answers like http://stackoverflow.com/a/2396461/294884

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for an answer to this and found a solution by myself.

I wanted to animate an SCNNode, but it should be easily done for any other custom object.

I made a subclass of `UIMotionEffect` and override `keyPathsAndRelativeValuesForViewerOffset(viewerOffset: UIOffset) -> [String : AnyObject]?`. My subclass is initialized with a `SCNNode` so it can modify its properties when tilting the phone. That way you can animate non-animatable properties.
Here is my swift code:

```
class SCNNodeTiltMotionEffect: UIMotionEffect {

    var node: SCNNode? // The object you want to tilt
    var baseOrientation = SCNVector3Zero
    var verticalAngle = CGFloat(M_PI) / 4
    var horizontalAngle = CGFloat(M_PI) / 4

    init(node: SCNNode) {
        super.init()
        self.node = node // Set value at init
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func keyPathsAndRelativeValuesForViewerOffset(viewerOffset: UIOffset) -> [String : AnyObject]? {
        // Set any properties of your object with values of viewerOffset attributes
        node?.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make(baseOrientation.x, baseOrientation.y + Float(viewerOffset.horizontal * horizontalAngle), baseOrientation.z - Float(viewerOffset.vertical * verticalAngle))
        return nil
    }
}
```

If you want to animate animatable properties, you should return a dictionary with keypaths and values or use `UIInterpolatingMotionEffect`, more details in [the official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIMotionEffect_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIMotionEffect/keyPathsAndRelativeValuesForViewerOffset:)