# secondary property update not sticking after animation

Tags: ios, caanimation

REPRO repository here: https://github.com/kaolin/38492498/tree/master

---

I have a `@property int percentScanned`.

I've set needsDisplayForKey:

```objective-c
+ (BOOL)needsDisplayForKey:(NSString *)key {
    if ([@"percentScanned" isEqualToString:key]) {
        return YES;
    }
    return [super needsDisplayForKey:key];
}
```

My display method:

```objective-c
- (void)display {
    _percentTextLayer.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d%%",[[self presentationLayer] percentScanned]];
}
```

My animation:

```
    [CATransaction begin];
    self.percentScanned = 99;
    _percentTextLayer.string=@"99%";
    [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
        _percentTextLayer.string=@"99%";
        self.percentScanned = 99;
    }];
    {
        CABasicAnimation *a = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"percentScanned"];
        [a setFromValue:@0];
        [a setToValue:@99];
        [a setDuration:4.];
        [self addAnimation:a forKey:@"percentage"];
    }
    [CATransaction commit];
```

This all works fine, except at the end of the animation, my model layer string goes back to "00%". As you can see, I've thrown what feels like the kitchen sink at forcing it to stay at "99%" (outside of the "hack" of `animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;` and `animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;`—and actually, adding those doesn't help!).

I *do* have another animation on the same layer about 3/30 of a second later, fading the opacity.... But pushing that out, or deleting it, doesn't seem to make a difference.

I know how to do this for standard animated values, but I'm missing something for how to do this with a secondary/evaluated value like this....

---

EDITED TO ADD:

Somewhere along the way, adding `animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;` and `animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;` did actually start "working", but I'd like to not leak animations....

If I add a setter for percentScanned, it's not called with 0 at the end, but display is called with 0 at the end. It's kind of hard to trace the link between setPercentScanned being called and display being called...

I can hack my `display` to read as follows:

```objective-c
- (void)display {
    if ([[self presentationLayer] percentScanned] != 0) {
        _percentTextLayer.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d%%",[[self presentationLayer] percentScanned]];
    }
}
```

Then it works for my particular use case, but that's still less than ideal....

And putting a breakpoint in the display method is fairly unhelpful (of course it's just happening inside display_if_needed). :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

percentScanned needed to be set as a @dynamic variable so that Core Animation implements the accessors for you, per https://stackoverflow.com/a/2396461/856925

Answer (score 0):

Basically, set the end value directly onto the layer and animate just the `fromValue`. So the value that the layer has is already correct at the end of the animation.

Comment: I believe that's what I've done above. The same pattern works for all my properties except this one which is special because it's not a default-animated property....

Comment: But the animation is running, add a conditional breakpoint on the value being set and check when it's set to zero

Comment: Apologies if I fail on following through; baby just came a couple weeks early.

Comment: Debugging, it looks like I'm just setting it once at the beginning to 0, then to 99 at the start of the animation, and then 0 to 99 in the animation.

Comment: If I add a setter for percentScanned, it's never called with 0, but display is called with 0 at the end. It's kind of hard to trace the link between setPercentScanned being called and display being called...

Comment: I'm not convinced you need the transaction, just set the final value and then animate from the start. you don't need to set the to value as it's already there

Comment: Hmm. Removed transaction, removed "to" value, ... is simplified, but is still jumping to "0" at the end. :/

Comment: Not sure why then :-(

Comment: Created https://github.com/kaolin/38492498/tree/master to show off the problem as minimally as I could.... :) Interestingly, I set the initial value to "HELLO WORLD", and it still resets to "00%" at the end.